# How can I rotate gridline labels on a cartopy map?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm plotting a map using Stamen tiles inside a matplotlib figure like so:

```
tiler=Stamen('terrain-background')
mercator=tiler.crs

ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs01[1,0], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax3.add_image(tiler,14)
```

I then attempt to rotate the gridline tick labels like so:

```
gl3=ax3.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True, linewidth=1., color='gray', alpha=0.75, linestyle='--')
gl3.left_labels=False
gl3.top_labels=False
gl3.xlabel_style={'size':10., 'color':'gray', 'weight':'bold'}
gl3.ylabel_style={'size':10., 'color':'gray', 'weight':'bold'}
gl3.rotate_labels=45
```

Unfortunately, nothing is rotated when I open the PNG file that I save in the script. Is there another way that I can rotate gridline tick labels?

Comment: `rotate_labels` is a boolean attribute. You can set it to `True` or `False`, but not the actual angle of rotation.

Comment: @DenisSergeev Ok I see that now, and then if it's set to true how can I go about actually rotating??

Answer (score 3):

Right, so I found an answer on the cartopy issue tracker.

You can change the rotation angle by setting

```py
gl3.xlabel_style = {'rotation': 45}
gl3.ylabel_style = {'rotation': 45}
```

Comment: If the `gridlines` object (here, `gl3`) is not there, can you use `plt.xticks(rotation=45)`, and `plt.yticks(rotation='vertical')`?

Comment: At the current version of cartopy, it does not seem to be possible to do it in this way, especially for a non-rectangular projection. I might be wrong though.

Comment: According to the document: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-ticklabels-rotation-py  it should work. Remember `basemap` was built on top of `matplotlib`. If basemap won't plot them, basic matlotlib features can help plot/manipulate.

Comment: This is not related to `basemap` though - this is about `cartopy`. The simple solution of using `plt.xticks()` won't work in `cartopy` because in `cartopy` tick labels need to be transformed according a georeferenced projection. Thus the best if not the only way of adding tick labels is to use the `ax.gridlines()` method.

Comment: Sorry about `basemap`, but `cartopy` is also based on `matplotlib`.

Comment: @DenisSergeev Unfortunately when I try the method in the answer, my labels disappear entirely!

Comment: @NaN Do they disappear too if you make the font size smaller?
If so, it might be a bug in cartopy, possibly related to this issue https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1609